# How can I add few css or js file into my plugin

Tags: plugins

I want do add few cs and js file into my plugin in admin panel. I create function style:

```
function style() {
wp_enqueue_style ( 'my-admin-theme', plugins_url ( 'style.css', __FILE__ ) );
wp_enqueue_script ( 'jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js', array (), '1.0.0', true );
wp_enqueue_script ( 'uploadfile', 'http://hayageek.github.io/jQuery-Upload-File/jquery.uploadfile.min.js', array (), '1.0.0', true );

}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'style' );
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'style' );
add_action ( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'style' );
add_action ( 'login_enqueue_scripts', 'style' );
```

When I check source code I see only style.css jquery.uploadfile.min.js. What is wrong ?

King regards

Comment: In enqueing action you should use function name `style` instead of `jquery` or `uploadfile`.

Comment: I change it to 'style" like in post but effect is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if( ! function_exists( 'style' )){

    function style() {
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
        wp_enqueue_style ( 'my-admin-theme', plugins_url ( 'style.css', __FILE__ ) );
        //wp_enqueue_script ( 'jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js', array (), '1.0.0', true ); // already included jQuery
        wp_enqueue_script ( 'uploadfile', 'http://hayageek.github.io/jQuery-Upload-File/jquery.uploadfile.min.js', array (), '1.0.0', true );
    }

        add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'style' );
        add_action ( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'style' );
        add_action ( 'login_enqueue_scripts', 'style' );

}else{
    echo 'Function already exists'; 
}
```

Try next code, but your code work. No need to include jQuery, because by default WP use it.